# Querying with mysql for mail retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I have a mail table that I need to retrieve all of the current user's incoming and outgoing mail in one query. As php loops through the results it builds one main visual based on the most recent message sent or received, and then needs to build previous messages visuals related to that most recent one(this would be seen under the most recent one going down the page). The Mail table I have is set up like this:

i`d(auto_incr), from_user(user id number), to_user(user id number),

orig_mess(id number of the first message in conversation),

status(0 for unread, 1 for read)`

As with any mail inbox I need to get the results ordered like this:
1) Unread messages sent to logged in user(ordered by id), and then any previous messages in each of those conversations after the newest

2) Read messages sent to logged in user OR messages sent from logged in user(all ordered by their id), and then of course any previous messages related to each conversation after the newest

Here is what I have treid so far:

```
     $result = mysql_query("(SELECT id FROM Mail WHERE Mail.to_user='37' AND   
       Mail.status='0' ORDER BY Mail.id DESC) UNION (SELECT id FROM Mail WHERE   
(Mail.to_user='37' AND Mail.status='1') OR   
(Mail.from_user='37') ORDER BY Mail.id DESC)")or die(mysql_error());
```

I have accomplished the result I am looking for using a query to get each of the newest messages in each conversation, and then performing another query for each conversation after that. The problem with doing it that way is that if a user has 20 conversations in their mailbox there are 21 queries happening to display them all. Any help on how I can accomplish this or if there is a better way to set a mail system up would be greatly appreciated.

I still have not come up with any reliable way to accomplish this. Anyone able to shed some light?

Comment: how does this end up running more than 1 query exactly?

Comment: I am not currently using that format. Currently I use one broad select query to get the most recent message sent or received to the user. Loop through the results. Run another query inside the loop selecting any other messages related to the one from the current loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. This will pull both sent and received messages in the same query and sort by the conversations with the latest unread message first, then the latest read message.

```
SELECT   <any fields you want>

FROM     Mail as m

     JOIN

     (SELECT  orig_mess, id, status
      FROM    Mail 
      WHERE   Mail.from_user='37' OR Mail.to_user='37'
      ) as latest ON m.orig_mess = latest.orig_mess
      AND latest.id = (SELECT  id  
                       FROM    Mail  
                       WHERE   from_user='37' OR to_user='37' 
                               orig_mess = latest.orig_mess
                       ORDER BY status asc, id DESC  
                       LIMIT 1)

WHERE    m.from_user='37' OR m.to_user='37'   

ORDER BY latest.status, latest.id DESC, m.status, m.id DESC
```

Comment: It looks promising to me. When I run it though I get the error "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous". here is my exact query:
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Mail as m JOIN
    (SELECT orig_mess,id,status FROM Mail WHERE Mail.to_user='37'
    OR Mail.from_user='37' ORDER BY status asc, id DESC LIMIT 1)
    as latest ON m.orig_mess=latest.orig_mess WHERE 
    Mail.to_user='37' OR Mail.from_user='37' ORDER BY 
    latest.status, latest.id DESC, id DESC")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: In your main `SELECT` section prefix any fields from the Mail table with `m.`.

Comment: I eliminated the error by using the original alias in the final where clause. But now it is only returning one value. updated query: ("SELECT m.id,m.to_user,m.from_user FROM Mail as m JOIN (SELECT orig_mess,id,status FROM Mail WHERE Mail.to_user='37' OR Mail.from_user='37' ORDER BY status asc, id DESC LIMIT 1) as latest ON m.orig_mess=latest.orig_mess WHERE m.to_user='37' OR m.from_user='37' ORDER BY latest.status, latest.id DESC, id DESC")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Sorry about that.  I hade made some edits to it.  Try it now.

Comment: It does work that way, but it only returns one row still. I'm wondering if how I am doing this is the wrong way lol.

Comment: Maybe I have something wrong.  I'll try to use www.sqlfiddle when I have a chance and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I just fixed one thing.  Try it again now.

Comment: It is very close. It gets all of the rows, but it is just not ordering them properly. It seems to just be ordering them from highest to lowest id. :(